# Uniform Convergence on Standard Probability Space

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-convergence, product-space

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a standard (or Lebesgue-Rokhlin) probability space. That is, $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is isomorphic to $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}_{0}}$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}([0,1]^{\mathbb{N}_{0}})$ and the product of the Borel measures $\lambda^{\mathbb{N}_{0}}$. Let $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}$ be the set of all $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables that are essentially bounded. Take any $X \in \mathcal{L}^{\infty}$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing function (and thus, the inverse $f^{-1}$ exists). Consider a sequence $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that:

1. $f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly increasing function, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
2. $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly on any compact set (as $n \to \infty$).

In this setting, I encountered the following statement:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (f_{n})^{-1} \circ \mathbb{E}[f_{n}(X)]
= (f)^{-1} \circ \mathbb{E}[f(X)].
\end{align*}

How is this equation justified? In particular, I cannot see how the fact that "$f_{n} \to f$ uniformly on any compact set" matters. Is the compactness related to the assumption that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is isomorphic to $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}_{0}}$, which is compact (due to Tychonoff's theorem)?

Thank you.

Comment: Without $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly you don't even have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{E}[f_n(X)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$: take $X \sim \text{Unif}([0,1])$ and let $f_n(x) = n x^n$. Then $f_n \rightarrow 0$ (not uniformly), and $\mathbb{E}[f_n(X)] = \frac{n}{n+1}\rightarrow 1$ while $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that the without uniform convergence, one may not be able to interchange limit and expectation. What I am being confused about is: the uniform convergence is guaranteed only on compact sets, but I cannot see how the uniform convergence is guaranteed (possibly by the compactness). It may be the case that the support of X is not compact.